# SQL Performance Advantages/Disadvantages of Modelling n to m relationship

Tags: sql

I have an n to m relationship between authors and books. There are two possibilities I am considering for modelling this.

The **first possibility** is an explicit n to m relationship.

Table Author

```
ID       Name
1        Follett  
2        Rowling
3        Martin
```

Table Books

```
ID     Title                        Category    Logic Time 
1        A Dance with Dragons      Fantasy        1
2        Harry Potter              Fantasy        3
3        The Key to Rebecca        Thriller       2
4        World without end         Drama          4
```

Table book_author

```
authorId       bookId
1           3  
2           2
3           1
1           4
```

The **second possibility** is to store the author id in the book. **EDIT** If there are several authors per book I would have to enter the book once for each author.

Table Author

```
ID       Name
1        Follett  
2        Rowling
3        Martin
```

Table Books

```
ID       Title                     Category       Logic Time    AuthorId
1        A Dance with Dragons      Fantasy         1           3
2        Harry Potter              Fantasy         3           2
3        The Key to Rebecca        Thriller        2           1
4        World without end         Drama           4           1
```

Assume I want to find out for a specific author (Ken Follett with id 1) the first book he published.

In the **first case** the query would look like:

```
    select * from books b join 
    book_author ba on b.id = ba.book_id
    where ba.author_id = 1
    order by b.logic_time asc;
```

In the **second case** the query would look like:

```
    select * from books b 
    where a.author_id = 1
    order by b.logic_time asc;
```

I am storing the ids of authors in the overlying system to avoid further joins with the author table. I am never interested in the details of authors. It is expected that there are a lot more books in the system than authors.

I am tending towards the first option since it is "cleaner" (EDIT: no duplicate book entries necessary), but I am having some troubles justifying this decision.

What is recommended from a **performance** point of view? I am guessing that the join should result in the first option being slower.

What about indexes that could be created to make the first option faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first option is a many-to-many relation. You would use that if there can be more than one author of a book (or zero authors of a book).

The second option is a one-to-many relation. You would use that if there can be only one author of a book.

So, you should pick the solution that fits what you are trying to do. Using the first option when the second option fits only opens up for inconsistencies, i.e. you could end up with books without authors or books with multiple authors.

Regarding performance either works fine. As long as there is an index to use (which is normally created for keys), a join is not a problem. For the second option you would add an index for the `AuthorId` field to make the lookup efficient.

Comment: I clarified the question, sorry.

Comment: @taranaki: In that case you need the first option.

Comment: hi, could you maybe explain a bit more why I need the first option? It's clear to me that the second option is really "ugly" sql, but I am mostly interested in the performance aspect of the two options. I never want to get all authors from one book. (the author book example is just a simplification for question asking purposes). Thank you for your help.

Comment: @taranaki: Using the second option for this is what's called denormalising for performance. You get redundancy in the database, which makes it harder to maintain the data, and the database can not protect you from inconsistencies in the data. It's also doubtful that you would get an actual performance gain, as the table would end up containing more data. I would definitely use the first option, and only go for the second option if there actually is a performance problem.

Answer (score 4):

What you describe are not two options to solve the same problem. Your first version is a n:m relation and it's just the "default" way to model such a relation. Your second version is just a 1:m mapping. The difference is, that in the first case book can be written by multiple authors. In the second case every book is written by just one author.

So make that absolutly excplicit: Your two "options" are two completly different use cases. If it's really m:n, you MUST use the first one!

Comment: My answer remains the same. If makes of course sense to use indexes to speed up your queries, but that's indepentend on the option you choose. Entering a book several times if it has multiple authors would be a very bad idea. What if you have to change for example the title of the book? You would have to change all records of that book. But what does "all" mean in that case? If it's n:m, use your first option.